# Asp.net javascript & css compression/file combination libraries

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, compression

I'm looking for recommendations for a library or framework to handle runtime combination/compression of css and js files in asp.net and MVC in particular.

The two leading contenders seem to be [Shinkansen](http://shinkansen.codeplex.com/) and [Client Dependency](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/).
Though [CSS Agent](http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/cssagent/) (CSS only) has some nice features like CSS constants.

I'm less interested in the compression side of things as I'm dubious of the benefits for our relatively low traffic sites but I like the idea of combining all the files into a single request and automating the caching & dependencies.

It seems strange that these libaries/frameworks don't seem to be more popular - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/). It's compile time, but works flawlessly.

As author says: "Chirpy has Godlike abilities". :)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd prefer runtime handling so as to have the option to control it by the debug setting in the web.config. Also I don't like the way a config file is required to combine the files - it seems more natural to do that within the includes on the page.